# Icon is not being rendered inside Semantic UI React Input field

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am using Semantic UI React. I'm trying to use the Input component, and send it an icon prop, exactly like shown in the official docs.

the icon is being added to the DOM, but I can not see the icon at all, and really don't understand why.

THANKS!!

here is the DOM. The icon is being rendered

[image]

Comment: Did you loaded semantic-ui styles? https://cdn.rtlcss.com/semantic-ui/2.4.1/semantic.css

Comment: hey. thank you for your answer. I did try to load it, even though it's not explicitly written in the Icons section. But it's still not working. Basically I copied-pasted the example from the Icons section, very simple & straight forward- but still its acting weird and not working. btw, there is a small type in the "search" word in the example, its not related to the problem (tried a lot of different examples from the docs)